# Change of variables between quadrilaterals - Rayleigh quotient

Tags: eigenvalues, geometric-measure-theory

A - Vertex at bottom left

B - Vertex at bottom right

K - Vertex at top left of blue quadrilateral

C - vertex at top left of brown quadrilateral

L - vertex at top right of blue quadrilateral

F - vertex at top right of brown quadrilateral.

Line Segment AB is fixed.

Suppose that 
$$|AC| = |CF| = |FB|$$ and quadrilateral ACFB is convex.

Construct the unique quadrilateral AKLB such that 
$$ |AKLB| = |ACFB|,  \quad \ |AK| = |KL| = |LB| \quad \text{and}\  \measuredangle{AKL} = \measuredangle KLB.$$

Given any function $f \in W^{1,2}(ACFB)$, consider the Rayleigh quotient:
$$ \frac{\int_{ACFB} |\nabla f|^2 \ dx }{\int_{ACFB} |f|^2 \ dx}$$

Question: Is there a nice (and invertible) change of variable from $T:ACFB \mapsto AKLB$ such that under this transformation, the new function $f^*(y) := f(T^{-1}y)$ for $y \in AKLB$ satisfies
$$ \frac{\int_{AKLB} |\nabla f^*|^2 \ dx }{\int_{AKLB} |f^*|^2 \ dx} \leq  \frac{\int_{ACFB} |\nabla f|^2 \ dx }{\int_{ACFB} |f|^2 \ dx}$$

Notation: $|AB|$ denotes length of the side $AB$ whereas $|ACFB|$ denotes the area of quadrilateral $ACFB$.

In particular, can I use the Homography transformation to get this inequality?

[image]

Comment: Does $|AKLB| = |ACFB|$ mean they have the same area? If so does it not mean that $ACFB$ was cyclic to begin with? (i.e., $\angle ACF = \angle CFB$)